# PHP Namespaces: why isn't my class found?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've read a bit about namespaces in PHP and how compser handles the autoloading of namespaces. I cannot figure out why my class cannot be found. Can someone help?

I'm using Laravel and here are the relevant bits:

`composer.json` relevant content:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Facebook\\":"vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/"
    }
}
```

doing a `composer dump-autoload` gives me the following line in `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`:

`'Facebook\\' => array($vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src'),`

And my vendor folder structure re: Facebook is:

```
vendor
   |__ facebook
         |__ php-sdk-v4
                  |__ src
                       |__ Facebook
                              |__ ..
                              |__ Facebook.php
                              |__ ..
```

Trying `$facebook = new Facebook($config)` gives me

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Class 'Facebook' not found

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Is `facebok` a typo or?

Comment: @vonUbisch yeah it was a typo, just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Facebook` is the name of the class, but `Facebook` seems to also be the name of your namespace.

In that case, you instance it like this:

```
$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook($config);
```

Comment: OK, when I do `new Facebook\Facebook($config)`  the class is found. but when I change the psr-0 to be `"Facebook\\":"vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook"` and do `new Facebook($config)` it doesn't find it. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because every class must live in a namespace. If you want to save yourself the extra `Facebook\ ` when instantiating, you can add `use Facebook;` to the beginning of your file.

Answer (score 2):

Anything from the vendor folder should be loaded automatically so there is no point for using these lines

```
"psr-0": {
    "Facebook\\":"vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/"
}
```

Have you added these lines to your composer.json and installed the library the usual composer way?

```
"require": {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "~5.0"
}
```

Comment: you're right. removing psr-0 didn't have any effect, so installing it with composer's `require` already loaded the namespace.